# PHP string to "unsigned long" (from C++)

Tags: php, c++, long-integer, unsigned, pack

I have this code in C++, which returns outputs the following number

```
int main(int argn, char** argv)
{
    cout << (*((unsigned long*)"P3TF")) << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I achieve the above in PHP (i.e. the string "P3TF" in unsigned long int). I tried using the pack method:

```
<?php
$lol = pack('N', 'P3TF');
var_dump( $lol, // returns jumbled up characters
          ord($lol[0]), // returns int 0
          ord($lol[1]), // returns int 0
          ord($lol[2]), // returns int 0
          ord($lol[3]), // returns int 0
          ord($lol[0]).ord($lol[1]).ord($lol[2]).ord($lol[3]) // returns 4 zeros as a string.
);
?>
```

I need it in bigendian byte order so I haven't used `pack('V')` or `pack('L')`.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The code in C++ is essentially wrong. It's nowhere guaranteed that `long` is 4 bytes long.

Comment: Also, the approach you use in C++ doesn't work in PHP; PHP doesn't let you jumble bytes, bits and addresses quite like C++. Strings are more abstract and can be multibyte in PHP.

Comment: The C++ code isn't actually mine, and it does work, I'm just trying to convert it to PHP.
As for the strings being multibyte, any way to get around this? Because this is going to be written to a file in `wb` mode.

Comment: @HoshSadiq: try running the C++ code on a 64-bit Linux machine, and come back and tell us that "it does work". ;)

Comment: I'm running it on a 64bit windows machine. Would it really make a difference (it's currently running on Windows 7 64bit with Dev-C++ with gcc on MinGW)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's literally `"P3TF"` in the real code, why not convert it once, and define a constant in the PHP code?

Failing that, you need [unpack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php), not pack. e.g. running

```
<?php
$in = 'P3TF';
$arr = unpack('N', $in);
printf("%08x\n", $arr[1]);
?>
```

Gives `50335446`, which is the ASCII codes for 'P' '3' 'T' 'F' in hex (concatenated)

Comment: Thanks for that! After reading your comment, I remember that the final file should actually have P3TF in the beginning (which is what I'm trying to achieve), however, I find it a bit strange because the C++ code is outputting `1179923280`. Any ideas why?

Comment: The string "P3TF" is 0x50, 0x33, 0x54, 0x46. If you treat these bytes as an unsigned long then it will become 0x46543350 which is 1179923280.